# Ansible : Add running EC2 instances to Auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am working on an Ansible project in which I would like to add to my Auto-scaling group an existing EC2 instance found by tag-Name. I was able to find it with an AMI or terminating the old instances. But I am simply looking for a way to add them to auto-scaling group like in web management console. Where I just right click on instance, select settings, attach it to auto-scaling group. Below code is all in 1 file.

Find EC2 instances:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - ec2_remote_facts:
          region: eu-central-1
          filters:
             "tag:Name": Ubuntu_From_AMI
       register: ec2found

     - name: Add found instances to group
       add_host: hostname="{{ item.public_ip_address }}" groups=ec2instances
       with_items: "{{ ec2found.instances }}"
```

Here is how I am adding the auto-scaling group :

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: Add auto-scaling groups.
       ec2_asg:
          name: magento_scaling_group
          load_balancers: 'LB_NAME'
          availability_zones: [ 'eu-central-1a', 'eu-central-1b', 'eu-central-1c' ]
          launch_config_name: "{{ lc.name }}"
          min_size: 0
          max_size: 5
          desired_capacity: 0
          vpc_zone_identifier: [ 'subnet-e712ad8c', 'subnet-e12e8dac', 'subnet-28e91a55' ]
          tags:
             - environment: production
               propagate_at_launch: no
```

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the current list of modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/list_of_all_modules.html), it appears there is no such functionality. You'll need to [create a new module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally) or just cheat and use the [`aws cli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) in a normal `command:` invocation. If you go the route of creating a new module, please do consider submitting it as a PR to the Ansible project so others will benefit from your work.

Comment: Ended up using AWS CLI. Thank you. :-)